# Finding addenth on array - JS

Tags: javascript, arrays

I created a function that will find pairs to add the two numbers that will be equal to the sum.

```
    function findingSum(arr, sum){
  var firstElement = [];
  var difference = [];
  var final = [];

  var convertArr = arr.map(function(item){
    return parseInt(item, 10);
  });


  for(var i = 0; i < convertArr.length; i++){
    difference.push(sum - convertArr[i]); // subtracted sum from each convertArr item

    if(difference[i] + convertArr[i] === sum){ // check if convertArr item was added to difference item === sum
         firstElement.push(convertArr[i]); // if so add the convertArritem to the result array
    }

    if(firstElement[i] + convertArr[i] == sum){
      final.push(firstElement[i], convertArr[i]);
    }
 }
  return final;
}

var addNumbers = findingSum([3, 34, 4, 12, 5, 2], 9);
console.log(addNumbers); // --> [4, 5]
```

So what I did is that I try to get the difference of `convertArr[i]` and the sum and put them in a `difference` variable. Then I tried to see if adding difference[i] from the original array will give me the sum. If so I'll add them on firstElement array and try to add each value to the original array and finally push them along with it's addenth if the sum was attain. So when you add this two you'll get the sum.

For some reason my logic doesn't work and it does'nt push things on both firstElement and final array. Can anyone help me with this?>

Comment: a pair of two that when you added them you'll get the sum.

Comment: first found only.

Comment: Nope. It's not.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a hash table for visited values.

```js
var findingSum = function (array, s) {
    var a, i,
        hash = Object.create(null);

    for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        a = array[i];
        if (hash[s - a]) {
            return [s - a, a];
        }
        if (!hash[a]) {
            hash[a] = true;
        }
    }
};

console.log(findingSum([3, 34, 4, 12, 5, 2], 9));  // [4, 5]
```

Comment: Nosebleed. I don't know how to use a hashtable LOL.